# Automate Windows Powershell input using python

Tags: python, powershell

I was creating powershell script and ran it using python, but I just realized that the command needs input from the user:

```
    Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Enable" on target "Win32_PnPEntity: HP Wide Vision HD Camera (DeviceID =
"USB\VID_04F2&PID_B735&MI_00\6&8C5F8A1&0...)".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Is there a way to automate this using python? or should I modify my powershell script to automate the input, or is there any better way?, Thanks!.

By the way i want the input is Y

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Maybe setting the [`$ConfirmPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#confirmpreference) variable could help?

Comment: Pass argument `-Confirm:$false` to hide the prompt and assume `Y`. If this doesn't work, try `-Force`.

Comment: -Confirm:$false argument actually worked, Thanks!

Comment: You can either prompt in powershell script or in python script.  Powershell script can take parameters and option that are entered in python can be passed to powershell as parameters.